# Goose for Christmas

Tags: goose

I want to cook my goose  on Christmas Day  for eating about 3pm. BUT I will not be at home from 10am - 2pm. Can I leave it to slow cook at a lower temperature during these hours and increase temperature when I return at 2pm to crisp skin? I do not want to cook it before Christmas Day. 
Many many thanks. A

Comment: Never done it with a goose, but it works for a turkey. Be sure the bird is well covered, or you can get dryness. I use one of those big old enameled roasters, with top cover and bottom piece: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=turkey+roaster&t=ffsb&iax=images&ia=images&iai=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ebayimg.com%2Fimages%2Fi%2F281874915287-0-1%2Fs-l1000.jpg Keeps things nice and moist.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger it seems a little cruel to choose duckduckgo for your search example when discussing cooking waterfowl! (and goose is much less prone to dryness than turkey, so it should work better, in fact when you turn the heat up, you might need to get rid of quite a lot of fat or it will be oily)

Comment: Although goose has a lot of fat it can go from moist to dry as a bone quickly, make sure you use a thermometer!